# Upload photo to facebook with tags

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, facebook-graph-api, tags

I'm creating a Facebook Flash app and I'm having trouble uploading a photo to Facebook with myself or friends tagged. I am stuck at this for a whole time now and couldn't find the solution
First of all here are the permissons I want the app to have.

```
ExternalInterface.call("redirect","appId","user_birthday,read_stream,publish_stream,user_photos,friends_photos","http://apps.facebook.com/appName");
```

Here is what I do to upload the photo to Facebook without tags (this works):

```
var params:Object = {name: 'My Card', image:card, message: 'Greetings from Barcelona' , fileName:'Card'};
Facebook.api('me/photos', onSaveToPhotoAlbumComplete, params);
```

But when I want to add tags of friends or myself it doesn't work, Here is what I did (In this case I only want to tag myself in the picture):

```
var params:Object = {name: 'Rosada Face-It', image:card, message:message, fileName:'Face It!', tags:[{"id":myId,"x":50,"y":50}]};
Facebook.api('me/photos', onSaveToPhotoAlbumComplete, params);
```

I also tried it with quotes and "tag_uid" instead of "id" but that is not the problem I think:

```
tags:'[{"tag_uid":"'+ editorModel.tag1 +'","x":"50","y":"50"}]'
```

If somebody could help?

Comment: Is an error returned when you try? If so, can you post the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the API I think a seperate call may be needed to add tags

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/

I think to create a tag you need to have the PHOTO_ID and then do a POST to `PHOTO_ID/tags`

```
var params:Object = {{"to":myId, "x":50, "y":50}]};
Facebook.api(photoId +"/tags", onPhotoTagged, params);
```